# How to use a Tkinter button to close OpenCV windows

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

Tkinter Button.py

```
import threading, cv2
from tkinter import *
from Colour_Detector import *

root1 = Tk()
root1.title('HSV Button')
root1.iconbitmap("D:\Computer Science\Python\Cube\Cube.ico")
root1.geometry('200x400')

##root2 = Tk()
##root2.title('Quit Button')
##root2.geometry('200x200')
def colour_det():
    colour_detector()

def myClickHSV():
    threading.Thread(target=colour_det).start()

def quiting():
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)

def quitButton():
    #threading.Thread(target=colour_det).stop()
    threading.Thread(target=quiting).start()
# Disabled Button
#myButton = Button(root, text='Click Me' state = DISABLED)

#Button with padx as x width and pady as y width
myButton1 = Button(root1, text='HSV', padx=85, pady=85, command=myClickHSV, fg='red', bg='yellow')
myButton1.pack()

myButton2 = Button(root1, text='Quit', padx=85, pady=85, command=quitButton)
myButton2.pack()

root1.update()
root1.mainloop()`
```

I have tried to close the windows using the button. When I use a keyboard input of 'q' it works and destroys the window but when I use the button the OpenCV windows just freeze and not respond anymore.

Comment: Mixing multiple GUI toolkits together in one program is not a good idea. If you use tkinter for your GUI, use it to display images as well, and don't use OpenCV's HighGUI functions. Furthermore, you're calling the HighGUI functions from another thread, which is usually asking for trouble as well.

Comment: and there are unescaped backslashes in your string literals. please review python's syntax, the syntax for strings specifically.